# I get a "serious errors while checking the disk drives for /boot" error while booting

Tags: boot, mount

I have just set up my new system by creating three partitions on a whole hard disk (`/boot`, `/home`, `swap` and `/`). I saw [**this**](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/05/04/manual-disk-partitioning-guide-for-ubuntu-11-04/) article and now I am getting those errors and the system provide me with some options: (**I** to ignore, **S** to skip mounting or **M** for manual recovery).

I am forced to choose skip mounting because I don't know what manual recovery is. Despite the error I get I think that the system boots okay because I can use the system but this error is very annoying.

Comment: 'Those errors'? What errors?

Comment: Same problem with me but when i go on ignore nothing... Another problem same nothing, and do not start ubuntu. After all ignore just black screen. What on manual recovery to write?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The message says some errors were found on the filesystem which **fsck** is afraid to fix automatically, so you need to do it manually. To do this, press **M** when it prompts you - this will drop you into a emergency root console. From there you'll be able to run

```
fsck /dev/sda1
```

where `/dev/sda1` is the name of your `/boot` partition. You can see the list of partitions by doing `fdisk -l`.

Alternatively, you can try `fsck -A` to check all partitions but I suppose it'll only work if the root partition is already mounted so `fsck` can access `/etc/fstab`.

It'll probably ask you a few questions - I usually just agree with what it proposes. Also, there's '**a**' option which will fix things automatically but the **man** file suggests to use it with caution. So, ultimately, `fsck -Aa` should fix all errors on all partitions without asking any questions.

After you're finished, exit the shell with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> and the machine will reboot.

Comment: I have the same problem but those steps doesn't work for me :( when i type fsck /dev/sda1 it says: there is differences between backup and original and give me 3 options: 2) Move Backup to Original, 2) Move Original to Backup 3) No changes when i choose 1 or 2 it says leaving file system unchanged. I reboot and same error found.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem except I had created a RAID volume formatted with XFS.  Every time the OS booted I would get the **`Serious errors were found...`** message. If I hit **`i`** to ignore, the volume would still mount fine.

All I had to do was install the **`xfsprogs`** package and run **`xfs_check`**.  The OS was probably trying to check the filesystem but failed because the utility wasn't there.

Thanks for steering me in the right direction Sergey!

Comment: +1. Yes, this was my case.  The file system was clean, but the OS couldn't determine that because (in my case) reiserfsprogs wasn't installed.

Comment: Do you remember exchange how to use this command? I'm running into this exact issue and I don't know how to use xfs_check (i never can understand the man pages).