# standard partitioning scheme for ubuntu home user

Tags: partitioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's your recommendation on drive partitioning schemes for a desktop and home server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247/whats-your-recommendation-on-drive-partitioning-schemes-for-a-desktop-and-home-s)

This thread is a continuation of [my failed attempt to install ubuntu on a new pc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58302/i-get-an-serious-errors-while-checking-the-disk-drives-for-boot-error-while-bo/58311#58311). Ive decided to reinstall ubuntu by using a simpler partitioning scheme. The one i made had four partitions (/,/boot,/home and swap) and after the booting i got the error i describe in the hyperlink above.

Ultimately which is the most standard partitioning scheme for a simple home user who does not need to install something else in this particular hard drive(320 GB ) ??? Please be specific regarding the type of partitions needed (size,type,primary or logical etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

two primary partitions as follows:

1) main, including root, boot and home
   most of the disk used except the space for the swap in (2)
   ext4
   this should be set as bootable and root

2) swap partition
   i've used double the amount of ram for my machine (eg 4GB RAM, swap size 8GB)
   linux swap
   set to swap

Hope that helps

Comment: the same scheme.

Comment: where should i put the bootloader(MBR or /)?

Comment: Or don't worry and just let the installer do the dirty thing for you... the best idea for a new user.

Comment: I would not follow this setup myself though. I would `always` advice to have at least 2 partitions: no matter how you set it up 1 partition should always be your data storage (the partition where you put your important files on). Always seperate your file from your system. Always.

Comment: @Vaios bootloader can go on either but for least hassles put it on MBR because then it won't be short circuited by anything else that does put a loader in the MBR as this is usually checked before checking any of the partitions

Comment: @Rinzwind he asked for simple :) but I would agree that if you're going to do more than play music of send mails the 3 partition system of Javier would be beter

Comment: That's true @Dirk but still it is our job also to educate when we see flaws in logic. This setup is a nightmare when you want to upgrade and the upgrade fails ;)

Answer (score 2):

While Dirk answer is the best option for a new user (don't worry about partitions), here is a quite popular and relative simple choice that I use:

1. Swap: 3 Gb, as big as memory to make hibernate work).
2. Root (/): 10 Gb, to keep the system files
3. Home (/home): Rest of disk (148 Gb for me), to keep my files.

It let's me upgrade, use betas, reinstall and just play with the system while keeping my important files in their own place. It's quite similar to the windows option of using two partitions (C: for system and D: for data), but it also keeps some configuration options on /home.

Comment: can u give the type of the partitions ? Like primary or logical , ext2 or etc

Comment: why would that matter Vaios? and +1 Javier!

Comment: All are primary partitions.