# Serious errors were found while checking the disk drive for /. - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, boot, system-installation, mount

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 with wubi inside Windows 7 and then after installation is completed and system is about to start it shows 
-Serious errors were found while checking the disk drive for /.

If I ignore then it shows:
-The disk drive for /tmp is not ready yet or not present

Then if I skip
-An error occurred while mounting /.

If I skip that too it shows Ubuntu 14.04 LTS tty1 requires login. and gui never shows.

Why does this happen? I tried reinstalling and same thing happens. Any idea?

Comment: These are signs that your hard-drive is dying. Promptly try to get important data off and replace it.

Comment: thanks. I didn't notice it ! and actually the answer was helpful.

Comment: yeah, hopefully it will give you enough time to get the important stuff off ;) before the extra sectors run out

Comment: @kostandinangjellari did you fix this issue?

Comment: How did you solve the error? I am working on a project which deciddes my graduation and I dont have the latest version of it on the cloud. This is urgent.

Comment: i followed the steps in this thread:
http://askubuntu.com/a/58311/270059

Comment: Not working for me :(

Comment: I found a solution here http://askubuntu.com/questions/453411/ubuntu-14-04-not-booting-after-error-message-temp-could-not-be-mounted it works perfectly!! Now i have my ubuntu 14.04 :D