# “serious errors while checking the disk drives for /boot” error while booting

Tags: boot

When I try to install ubuntu 14.04 I get this error after installing the system and trying to boot for the first time. I saw this article [I get a "serious errors while checking the disk drives for /boot" error while booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58302/i-get-a-serious-errors-while-checking-the-disk-drives-for-boot-error-while-bo)

But, it does not helped me. I cannot boot ubuntu. I'm installing it into my Windows 8.1. 
No matter witch option i choose ( (I to ignore, S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery)), cannot boot. Any solution to this ?

Comment: I have the same problem :/ After upgrade from 13.10, i does not boot Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: have you try to edit the mount point at fstab, with ubuntu recovery mode?

Answer (score 0):

Instaling from inside windows is a secure and user-friendly way of installing ubuntu but it's better to install from a usb/disk. you'll get more performance and resize partition more than wubi can support(30gb).
It's independent from windows and you will not lose boot into windows.
Only drawback is replacing windows boot with grub but that's not big deal.
I encountered same problem in my laptop found solution in post you've  linked your question with but never worked on my pc. don't know why. 
anyway I installed it via usb and it works superb.
If you want to experience ubuntu in its max performance I recommend installing from USB/CD