# What does this Ubuntu boot error mean - "Errors were found while checking the disk drive for /."?

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I've been dual booting a late 2008 Macbook 5,1 with OS X and Ubuntu 14.10
for over a year with no problems using rEFInd with no problems.

Last week I updated the software on the Ubuntu installation.

Now I get "Errors were found while checking the disk drive for /."

If I press any of the options at this point e.g. F for 'fix' or I for 'ignore', nothing happens.

On the recovery menu the keyboard is unresponsive and I cannot proceed with it.

I managed to get to the login screen, once or twice, but my account password won't log me in, and in fact if you select guest, it won't log you in either.

Still booting fine to OS X.

I'm not a Linux expert, any constructive comments appreciated.

It's been suggested this is a duplicate question. My issue differs in at least 2 respects from the suggested duplicate. 1. I get "Errors" not "Serious Errors"
2. I cannot skip, ignore or fix them and proceed to boot.

Comment: What exactly did you update? Can you access your Ubuntu partition from OSX? I am guessing that rEFInd can't find the `/` partition but I don't know much about rEFInd. If it has a tool to detect partitions, you should be ab;e to do something equivalent to what is described [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109492/22222) for grub.

Comment: @terdon thanks for your suggestions. rEFInd loads first and lets me choose os x or Ubuntu. If I choose os x, this boots fine. If I choose Ubuntu, grub 2 starts. If I choose Ubuntu from the grub menu, I get the above error. If I choose Ubuntu (recovery mode), then the recovery menu displays, but the keyboard is completely unresponsive. I don't know how to access the Ubuntu partition from OSX, but I can boot a live linux disc and access partitions this way.

Comment: @terdon The updates were just the ones Ubuntu suggested when I checked for updates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I get a "serious errors while checking the disk drives for /boot" error while booting](http://askubuntu.com/questions/58302/i-get-a-serious-errors-while-checking-the-disk-drives-for-boot-error-while-bo)

Comment: @David Foerster I don't think it's a duplicate - I get "errors" not "serious errors", and I cannot boot or do anything but drop to a grub command line. The user with the issue you reference could boot their system despite the errors.

Comment: Did you read the link I posted in my first comment? Try booting a live CD and following the instructions in my answer there. That might solve it.

Comment: @terdon I followed your instructions and was able to boot from a live cd and recover my data. I then re-installed ubuntu. Thanks for the help, sorry for the late reply. Mind you, I still have no idea what caused the problem.